# Downloaded pyautogui but not importing and the version is also not showing

Tags: python, module

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xx3TP.png)I m downloaded pyautogui module and in the screen screen it is showing that is downloaded but when i am importing its shows
Traceback (most recent call last):   File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pyautigui'

I have tried to reinstall it but not comming to the conclusion

Comment: Please include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code (text, not photo) necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. It may be helpful to read about [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). You should also read [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0):

If the error states specifically "ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pyautigui'" then it means there is typo in the import line. Should be pyaut**o**gui, not pyaut**i**gui